# Getting (415) Unsupported Media Type error

Tags: c#, json, http, post, httpwebrequest

What I have to do is that I have to post JSON data in given URL
Where my JSON looks like

```
{
    "trip_title":"My Hotel Booking",
    "traveler_info":{
        "first_name":"Edward",
        "middle_name":"",
        "last_name":"Cullen",
        "phone":{
            "country_code":"1",
            "area_code":"425",
            "number":"6795089"
        },
        "email":"asdv@gmail.com"
    },
    "billing_info":{
        "credit_card":{
            "card_number":"47135821",
            "card_type":"Visa",
            "card_security_code":"123",
            "expiration_month":"09",
            "expiration_year":"2017"
        },
        "first_name":"Edward",
        "last_name":"Cullen",
        "billing_address":{
            "street1":"Expedia Inc",
            "street2":"108th Ave NE",
            "suite":"333",
            "city":"Bellevue",
            "state":"WA",
            "country":"USA",
            "zipcode":"98004"
        },
        "phone":{
            "country_code":"1",
            "area_code":"425",
            "number":"782"
        }
    },
    "marketing_code":""
}
```

And my function

```
string message = "URL";
_body="JSON DATA";
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(message) as HttpWebRequest;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_body))
{
    request.ContentType =  "text/json";
    request.Method =  "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(_body);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
}

using (HttpWebResponse webresponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

And when I am posting it; I am getting an error

> "The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type."

Anybody have idea about it; where I am mistaking?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am stuck with a very similar issue [that I posted about here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381385/system-net-webexception-when-sending-json-using-post-request-to-a-jira-api)

Comment: I resolved this error by changing an envelope namespace from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' to 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'...

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
request.ContentType =  "application/json"
```

Comment: Tried it but no luck.Thanks for the reply

Comment: If this doesn't work, it means that the server side is not expecting Json, so the problem is on the server side not the client.

Comment: for me this worked, it seems that I had to specify that the request was a json

Answer (score 9):

**For WebAPI** >> If you are `calling this POST method from fiddler`, just add this below line in the header.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: I thought that HttpWebRequest.ContentType already adds this to the header collection? See [HttpWebRequest.Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 3):

As answered by others the issue is with the ContentType. Should be 'application/json'.

Here is a sample with the old WebRequest

```
var parameters = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

var req = WebRequest.Create(uri);

req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/json";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);

req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (var os = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    os.Close();
}

var stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

if (stream != null)
    using (stream)
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
return "Response was null";
```

Answer (score 1):

I renamed my project and updated all of the namespaces to correlate after which I got this exact same message.
I realized that I had not updated the namespaces in the web.config (name and contract):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="X.Y.Z.Authentication" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="X.Y.Z.IAuthentication" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="defaultRestJsonp"></endpoint>
    </service>
  </...>
</..>
```

Hope this helps anyone reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure but I guess you have to send the text as a byteArray, try this:

```
req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/json";
        byte[] byteArray2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
        req.ContentLength = byteArray2.Length;
        Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(byteArray2, 0, byteArray2.Length);
        newStream.Close();
```

Comment: Tried it but no luck.Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

this is sample of a code i created for web api function that accepts json data

```
string Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(Serialized, Encoding.Unicode, "application/json"); 
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:1234", content);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the data you want to pass and encode it. Also, mention 
req.ContentType = "application/json";

"martin " code works.

```
LoginInfo obj = new LoginInfo();

obj.username = uname;
obj.password = pwd;
var parameters = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

var req = WebRequest.Create(uri);

req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/json";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);

req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (var os = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    os.Close();
}

var stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

if (stream != null)
    using (stream)
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
```